# MariaDB 10.3.3 Galera cluster adding new node in existing cluster # WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete

Tags: rsync, mariadb, cluster

I am trying to add new galera cluster node in existing MariaDB Master-Master setup, but i am seeing SST waiting for longer time and mariadb services failing to start. services status output as below,

```
2019-03-06  4:48:24 0 [Note] WSREP: Shifting OPEN -> PRIMARY (TO: 5522445)
2019-03-06  4:48:24 2 [Note] WSREP: State transfer required:
        Group state: 72542dfe-1f6a-11e9-8491-637f579e0d43:5522445
        Local state: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
2019-03-06  4:48:24 2 [Note] WSREP: New cluster view: global state: 72542dfe-1f6a-11e9-8491-637f579e0d43:5522445, view# 66: Primary, number of nodes: 3, my index: 0, protocol version 3
2019-03-06  4:48:24 2 [Warning] WSREP: Gap in state sequence. Need state transfer.
2019-03-06  4:48:24 2 [Note] WSREP: Setting wsrep_ready to 0
2019-03-06  4:48:24 0 [Note] WSREP: Running: 'wsrep_sst_rsync --role 'joiner' --address '<JOINER_ID>' --datadir '/app/mariadb10310/mysql/'   --parent '17682' --binlog '/app/mariadb10310/mysql/Galera_3_bin' --binlog-index '/app/mariadb10310/mysql/Galera_3_bin_log.index''
2019-03-06  4:48:24 2 [Note] WSREP: Prepared SST request: rsync|<JOINER_ID>:4444/rsync_sst
2019-03-06  4:48:24 2 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
2019-03-06  4:48:24 2 [Note] WSREP: REPL Protocols: 9 (4, 2)
2019-03-06  4:48:24 2 [Note] WSREP: Assign initial position for certification: 5522445, protocol version: 4
2019-03-06  4:48:24 0 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
2019-03-06  4:48:24 2 [Warning] WSREP: Failed to prepare for incremental state transfer: Local state UUID (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) does not match group state UUID (72542dfe-1f6a-11e9-8491-637f579e0d43): 1 (Operation not permitted)
         at galera/src/replicator_str.cpp:prepare_for_IST():482. IST will be unavailable.
2019-03-06  4:48:24 0 [Note] WSREP: Member 0.0 (seadb01a-u1-inf) requested state transfer from '*any*'. Selected 1.0 (maridb1bo-w1-ap)(SYNCED) as donor.
2019-03-06  4:48:24 0 [Note] WSREP: Shifting PRIMARY -> JOINER (TO: 5522445)
2019-03-06  4:48:24 2 [Note] WSREP: Requesting state transfer: success, donor: 1
2019-03-06  4:48:24 2 [Note] WSREP: GCache history reset: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:0 -> 72542dfe-1f6a-11e9-8491-637f579e0d43:5522445
2019-03-06  4:48:26 0 [Note] WSREP: (12ae32d9, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection to peer 12ae32d9 with addr tcp://<JOINER_ID>:4567 timed out, no messages seen in PT3S
2019-03-06  4:48:27 0 [Note] WSREP: (12ae32d9, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') turning message relay requesting off
2019-03-06  4:48:34 0 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete. current seqno: 5522141 waited 10.000000 secs.
2019-03-06  4:48:44 0 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete. current seqno: 5522141 waited 20.000000 secs.
2019-03-06  4:48:54 0 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete. current seqno: 5522141 waited 30.000000 secs.
2019-03-06  4:49:04 0 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete. current seqno: 5522141 waited 40.000000 secs.
2019-03-06  4:49:14 0 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete. current seqno: 5522141 waited 50.000000 secs.
2019-03-06  4:49:24 0 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete. current seqno: 5522141 waited 60.000000 secs.
2019-03-06  4:49:34 0 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete. current seqno: 5522141 waited 70.000000 secs.
2019-03-06  4:49:44 0 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete. current seqno: 5522141 waited 80.000000 secs.
Terminated
WSREP_SST: [INFO] Joiner cleanup. rsync PID: 17745 (20190306 04:49:53.642)
2019-03-06  4:49:54 0 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete. current seqno: 5522141 waited 90.000000 secs.
WSREP_SST: [INFO] Joiner cleanup done. (20190306 04:49:54.149)
2019-03-06  4:50:04 0 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete. current seqno: 5522141 waited 100.000000 secs.
2019-03-06  4:50:14 0 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete. current seqno: 5522141 waited 110.000000 secs.
2019-03-06  4:50:24 0 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete. current seqno: 5522141 waited 120.000000 secs.
2019-03-06  4:50:34 0 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete. current seqno: 5522141 waited 130.000000 secs.
2019-03-06  4:50:44 0 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete. current seqno: 5522141 waited 140.000000 secs.
2019-03-06  4:50:54 0 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete. current seqno: 5522141 waited 150.000000 secs.
2019-03-06  4:51:04 0 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete. current seqno: 5522141 waited 160.000000 secs.
2019-03-06  4:51:14 0 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete. current seqno: 5522141 waited 170.000000 secs.
2019-03-06  4:51:24 0 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete. current seqno: 5522141 waited 180.000000 secs.
2019-03-06  4:51:34 0 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete. current seqno: 5522141 waited 190.000000 secs.
2019-03-06  4:51:44 0 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete. current seqno: 5522141 waited 200.000000 secs.
2019-03-06  4:51:54 0 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete. current seqno: 5522141 waited 210.000000 secs.
2019-03-06  4:52:04 0 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete. current seqno: 5522141 waited 220.000000 secs.
2019-03-06  4:52:14 0 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete. current seqno: 5522141 waited 230.000000 secs.
2019-03-06  4:52:24 0 [Note] WSREP: Waiting for SST to complete. current seqno: 5522141 waited 240.000000 secs.
2019-03-06  4:52:24 0 [ERROR] WSREP: Process completed with error: wsrep_sst_rsync --role 'joiner' --address '<JOINER_ID>' --datadir '/app/mariadb10310/mysql/'   --parent '17682' --binlog '/app/mariadb10310/mysql/Galera_3_bin' --binlog-index '/app/mariadb10310/mysql/Galera_3_bin_log.index': 3 (No such process)
2019-03-06  4:52:24 0 [ERROR] WSREP: Failed to read uuid:seqno and wsrep_gtid_domain_id from joiner script.
2019-03-06  4:52:24 0 [ERROR] WSREP: SST failed: 3 (No such process)
2019-03-06  4:52:24 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2019-03-06  4:52:24 0 [Warning] WSREP: 1.0 (maridb1bo-w1-ap): State transfer to 0.0 (seadb01a-u1-inf) failed: -255 (Unknown error 255)
2019-03-06  4:52:24 0 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs_group.cpp:gcs_group_handle_join_msg():737: Will never receive state. Need to abort.
```

Comment: Issue still open but additional points tried to fix the issue,  migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf timeoutsec=36000 , /etc/rsyncd.conf --> max connections = 20 and timeout = 36000 on the source and target end, nothing worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to share the workaround after doing all brainstorm.
As new node was in remote location and faced SST issue.
1. take backup from existing node and restore on new galera cluster node.
  make sure that copy grastate.dat on backup dump location with same existing contain.
2. Once backup completed, make necessary changes in server.cnf file 
3. start the mariadb services on new node and monitor the log file.
Thanks.